# Windows support for Electron application created via Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, capacitor

I have just started looking at [Capacitor](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com) as a possible solution to package my hybrid apps in an electron shell. This is the first time I have used Electron, so really know very little about it's details.

I ran through the following steps..

```
1. Create new Ionic app
2. install capacitor as per doco
3. run   npx add electron
4. cd electron
5. npm i electron-packager -g
6. electron-packager . --platform=win32
```

I ended up with a subfolder `electron\capacitor-app-win32-x64`that contained an executable, which ran fine on both my dev machine (Windows 10 x64), and another Windows (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard x64).

My ultimate target device is a specialised small ruggedised tablet, that runs Windows 7 **Embedded** 32 bit.

It does not run on this, I get `The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running`. I am not even sure if the build app is managed or unmanaged (assuming unmanaged?)

So, I would like to know what is not compatible about the Windows machine. Initial questions are

1. How do I Know what "bitness" the Electron app is (ie 32 bit, 64 bit, or is it .net to is like "any cpu"). I can't see where to find out this information (dotpeek won't open the exe, and opening the exe in Visual Studio, I don't see much information)
2. Could it be it is not build for the correct CPU?
3. Is there some other dependency that perhaps the embedded Windows 7 has not got

Any help is how to figure this out would be great!

**[UPDATE1]**

Following some advice as given [here](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/3-ways-learn-whether-windows-program-64-bit-or-32-bit), it appears it is a 64 bit application, which is strange as the command `electron-packager . --platform=win32` appear to indicate we want a 32 bit. So that may be my problem.

Does anyone know how to make it build to 32bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. Just need to add a `--arch=ia32` to get 32 bit.

So my complete build command was

`electron-packager . --platform=win32 --arch=ia32`

and it is now 32 bit and runs on the 32 bit machine.